# Why is the JavaScript code not changing Values?

Tags: javascript, html, css, browser, getelementbyid

I am just returning to Web Dev(After learning another Language), and I just thought of a project, a text keyboard(When the mouse clicks on the desired alphabet, it adds that to a string), but the JS code is not working properly.
I was just seeing whether I can change the value of a `<p>` tag, but it is not changing, or should I say appearing.

```css
a{
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
}
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#heading{
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: 420 bold;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px red;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
#description{
    color: green;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 19px;
    font-weight: 69 bold;
    font-family: serif;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px white;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
#field{
    color: white;
}
#testSubject{
    width: 100px;
    height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style="background-color:black; margin:0;padding:0;" lang="en-US">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0"/>
<meta name="description" content="The text keyboard provides the user to write text and copy it without the use of keyboard!"/>
<title>Text Keyboard | website.com</title>
<style>

</style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 id="heading">
        Text Keyboard
    </h1>
    <p id="description">Just press the alphabet you want and see the magic!</p>
    <div id="keyboard">
        <p id="field"></p>
    </script>
    <button type="button" onclick="change()" value="Click Me!" id="testSubject">
    </div>
        <!--Always add the script on the bottom of the BODY tag since it contains the script-->
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function change(){
                document.getElementById("field").value = "This changed just now!";
            }
        </script>
</body>
</html>
```

, when I try to print the `value` of the Field tag, it prints out the text, but on the browser, nothing changes. Am I skipping some details or what, since even after reading and trying out other questions on StackOverflow, nothing changes.
Please Help.

Comment: Hi, Use `innerHTML` instead of using `value` in JS.

Comment: Only input elements have a `.value` property.

Comment: Or [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent)

Comment: As a rule of thumb use `textContent` not `innerHTML` when possible, because latter makes your app vulnerabel to [Cross-site Scripting Attacks](https://dev.to/caffiendkitten/innerhtml-cross-site-scripting-agc).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change 2 things

- First you need to use `textContent` or `innerHTML` to change text as
  `document.getElementById("field").textContent = "This changed just now!";`

and below is an **optional** change (if you want to color it in white)

- You need to change color to see the changes else it is invisible because color is white.

  `#field { color: black; }`

```js
function change() {
  document.getElementById("field").textContent = "This changed just now!";
}
```

```css
a {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#heading {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 420 bold;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px red;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

#description {
  color: green;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 19px;
  font-weight: 69 bold;
  font-family: serif;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px white;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

#field {
  color: black;
}

#testSubject {
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<h1 id="heading">
  Text Keyboard
</h1>
<p id="description">Just press the alphabet you want and see the magic!</p>
<div id="keyboard">
  <p id="field"></p>
  </script>
  <button type="button" onclick="change()" value="Click Me!" id="testSubject">Test</button>
</div>
```

Comment: The optional change is wrong since I have set the background color to black, so white is visible.

Answer (score 1):

Either use a text input:

```
<input type="text" />
```

That could be the better option but of course doesn't have to be.

Or use innerHTML:

```
document.getElementById("field").innerHTML = "This changed just now!";
```

That will fix your issue.

Answer (score 0):

`.value = x` will not work for a `div`, `value` should only really be used for inputs. Try using `innerHTML` instead.

```js
function change(){
  document.getElementById("field").innerHTML = "This changed just now!";
}
```

```css
a{
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
}
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#heading{
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: 420 bold;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px red;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
#description{
    color: green;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 19px;
    font-weight: 69 bold;
    font-family: serif;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px white;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
#field{
    color: white;
}
#testSubject{
    width: 100px;
    height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style="background-color:black; margin:0;padding:0;" lang="en-US">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0"/>
<meta name="description" content="The text keyboard provides the user to write text and copy it without the use of keyboard!"/>
<title>Text Keyboard | website.com</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 id="heading">
        Text Keyboard
    </h1>
    <p id="description">Just press the alphabet you want and see the magic!</p>
    <div id="keyboard">
        <p id="field"></p>
        <button type="button" onclick="change()" value="Click Me!" id="testSubject"></button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```